# How can I get the color histogram inside the circle in the image or the gradient distribution in the circle?

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform, color-detection

I have detected circular objects in the image with OpenCV and C++ and using houghcircle function. But I would like to filter out only those circle that have dark color (it should be the airplane door window). So I thought to use the color histogram inside the detected circle in the image or the gradient distribution in those circle to filter out .It works on some images like in the image provided. But when there are more circles in the image does not find the dark circle. Also I played with canny threshold but I would like it do happened automatically. So basically how to make the program more robust?

Firstly here is the code in C++ using OpenCV and C++

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int thresh = 200;
int max_thresh = 400;
Mat src;
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

int main()
{

             cv::Mat src = cv::imread("d4.png");
             resize(src, src, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);

              char* source_window = "Source";
              namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
              imshow( source_window, src );

              createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
              thresh_callback( 0, 0 );



waitKey(0);
return(0);
}

void thresh_callback(int, void* ) {

      Mat src_gray;
       cv::Mat bgr_image = cv::imread( "d4.png");
       cv::Mat orig_image = bgr_image.clone();
            cvtColor( bgr_image, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2HSV );

            medianBlur(src_gray, src_gray, 3);
     Mat canny_output;
    Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*3.5, 3 );

    // Threshold the HSV image, keep only the black pixels
    cv::Mat lower_black_hue_range;
    cv::Mat upper_black_hue_range;

    cv::inRange(canny_output, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(10, 10, 40), lower_black_hue_range);
    cv::inRange(canny_output, cv::Scalar(0,0, 41), cv::Scalar(10, 15, 50), upper_black_hue_range);

    // Combine the above two images
    cv::Mat black_hue_image;
    cv::addWeighted(lower_black_hue_range, 1.0, upper_black_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, black_hue_image);

    cv::GaussianBlur(black_hue_image, black_hue_image, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

    // Use the Hough transform to detect circles in the combined threshold image
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
    cv::HoughCircles(black_hue_image, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, black_hue_image.rows/1, 10, 100, 10, 0);

    // Loop over all detected circles and outline them on the original image
    if(circles.size() == 0) std::exit(-1);
    for(size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[current_circle][0]), cvRound(circles[current_circle][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[current_circle][2]);
        cv::circle(orig_image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
    }
    // Show images
     resize(lower_black_hue_range, lower_black_hue_range, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
     char* source_window1 = "Threshold lower image";
     namedWindow( source_window1, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( source_window1, lower_black_hue_range );
    //cv::namedWindow("Threshold lower image", cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    //cv::imshow("Threshold lower image", lower_black_hue_range);
     resize(upper_black_hue_range, upper_black_hue_range, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
     char* source_window2 = "Threshold upper image";
     namedWindow( source_window2, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( source_window2, lower_black_hue_range );
     //cv::namedWindow("Threshold upper image", cv::INTER_CUBIC);
     //cv::imshow("Threshold upper image", upper_black_hue_range);

     resize(black_hue_image, black_hue_image, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
     char* source_window3 = "Combined threshold images";
     namedWindow( source_window3, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( source_window3, black_hue_image );

    //cv::namedWindow("Combined threshold images", cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    //cv::imshow("Combined threshold images", black_hue_image);
     resize(orig_image, orig_image, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
     char* source_window4 = "Detected black circles on the input image";
     namedWindow( source_window4, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( source_window4, orig_image );
    //cv::namedWindow("Detected black circles on the input image", cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    //cv::imshow("Detected black circles on the input image", orig_image);


}
```

Input image of good detected circle
[image: Input Image 1]

The output is correct
[image: Correct black circle]

Second image with more circles
[image: complex image with different circles color]

The output is wrong, wrong detected circle
[image: Wrong detected circle]

Any help?

Comment: You're more likely to get answers by providing input image, showing what you've tried, how and why it didn't work and  what errors you're  getting. Please also read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, I have edit all necessary changes as you required. Please can I get some help now

Comment: There is no change in the post !

Comment: Sorry, now is ok. Please check

Comment: I made all the necessary changes. Please check it now